# jQuery cannot deserialize json object properly

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I cannot succeed to deserialize JSON object passed from c# code behind. I have been working on this 3 hours and couldn't understand the reason.

Here is my json object creation

```
struct specialitiy_struct {
    public int id;
    public string name;
};

[WebMethod]
public static string get_specialities(string ProfessionalID)
{
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("Connection");
    DbCommand dbCommand;
    dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("Select_Profes_Speciality");
    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "prof_id", DbType.Int16, Convert.ToInt16(ProfessionalID));
    IDataReader dr = db.ExecuteReader(dbCommand);

    List<specialitiy_struct> my_list = new List<specialitiy_struct>();
    specialitiy_struct my_speciality;

    while (dr.Read()) {
        my_speciality = new specialitiy_struct();
        my_speciality.id = Convert.ToInt16(dr["SpecialtyID"].ToString().Trim());
        my_speciality.name = dr["SpecialtyName"].ToString().Trim();
        my_list.Add(my_speciality);
    }
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Serialize(my_list);
}
```

and here is jquery code which deserialize the json object

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "NotificationSettings.aspx/get_specialities",
     data: "{'ProfessionalID':'" + <%= Session["ProflId"].ToString().Trim() %> + "'}",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data, status) {
       $.each(data, function (dt) {
          var mydata = data.d;
          var obj = $.parseJSON(mydata);
          $("#txt_speciality").tokenInput("add", { name: obj.name, id: obj.id});
       });
     }
});
```

The returned json object is this

```
 d: "[{"id":67,"name":"Kardiyoloji"},{"id":1,"name":"Acil Tip"}]"
```

I cannot deserialize the json object properly, please help me to do it?

Comment: But what is happening when you are deserializing ? is there any error message ?

Comment: What does the serialized json look like? (Run the api request in fiddler, and see what it returns)

Comment: I added the json object above. Sorry, I had the put it at the begining

Comment: `d: "[{"id":67,"name":"Kardiyoloji"},{"id":1,"name":"Acil Tip"}]"` Does not look like valid json to me. `{ d: [{"id":67,"name":"Kardiyoloji"},{"id":1,"name":"Acil Tip"}] }` would be more appropriate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is (partly) because `data.d` is an array of objects, not a single object, so you can't access `name` and `id` properties of it to get useful information (it doesn't have any). I suspect what you should actually be doing is iterating over `data.d`, not `data`, like so:

```
var d = $.parseJSON(data.d);
$.each(d, function(index, dt) {
    $("#txt_speciality").tokenInput("add", { name: dt.name, id: dt.id});
});
```

If you're returning valid JSON from the server then there should be no need for you to parse it yourself. If you're returning a JSON object that has JSON string properties then you should change that since there's absolutely no need to do it that way.

Comment: what you said makes sense but I am not sure how to do it. can you please give me a complete code?

Comment: @Borsel I'd need to know exactly what's being returned by the server; if you're using Firebug then you can see the response of AJAX requests in the Console, copy that and edit it into the question.

Comment: it returns this     {"d":"[{\"id\":67,\"name\":\"Kardiyoloji\"},{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Acil Tip\"}]"}

Comment: @Borsel Two options. 1. Change `d` from being a JSON string to actually being an array (essentially drop the double-quotes around it) - you'll likely need to change your server-side code to do that, however, and I can't help with that (I'm not a C#/ASP.NET programmer). 2. Parse the JSON string `d` to get the actual array, and then iterate over that; I've edited my answer to do that. Option 1 is the way you should really do it, but option 2 is easier to implement quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each($.parseJSON(data.d), function (key, value) {
        $("#txt_speciality").tokenInput("add", {
            name: value.name,
            id: value.id
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok, could you please show a sample json data?? may be just put a `console.log(data)` inside the `success` method. and paste the result here...

Comment: @Will.i.am Using `console.log(data)` won't be much help since the console display of an object/array doesn't usually match valid JSON structure. Ideally we want the string before it's parsed, not the resulting object.

Comment: {"d":"[{\"id\":67,\"name\":\"Kardiyoloji\"},{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Acil Tip\"}]"}

Comment: this is the response from the server. I got this response from the chrome tool

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue lies here:

```
$.each(data, function (dt) { // <----dt here
      var mydata = data.d; //<----data.d data here
```

Change to this:

```
success: function (data, status) {
   $.each(data, function (i, dt) {
      var mydata = dt.d;
      var obj = $.parseJSON(mydata);
      $("#txt_speciality").tokenInput("add", { name: obj.name, id: obj.id});
   });
 }
```

`d: "[{"id":67,"name":"Kardiyoloji"},{"id":1,"name":"Acil Tip"}]"`

Does not seem to be a valid json object to loop through.

Comment: That's because he is getting json encoded strings wrapped in `" "` which need to be parsed. Otherwise, well these are just strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
success: function (data, status) {
           var mydata = $.parseJSON(data);           
           $.each(mydata, function (index, element) {
              $("#txt_speciality").tokenInput("add", { name: element.name, id: element.id});
           });
         }
```

If this works, the JSON content type is probably not set correctly.

Comment: this gives error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null